# HTML Docs can't find

Tags: html, django

I'm looking for docs that discuss what these things are:

base.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
            <title>My Site - {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            {% block footer %}
                &copy; Copyright 2014 by <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">Me</a>.
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Specifically things like:

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

I'm trying to understand where I would place my CSS stylesheets and other elements into the base.html

For example where would I place a menu system that spans across all of my pages in my base.html

Are there any docs on this subject. I can't seem to find anything other than w3fools...

Comment: hehe, just a place holder!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

Answer (score 2):

Django has excellent documentation which is easy to find:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

Your `base.html` will contain the HTML code that is common across all the templates that are based on it (templates which use `{% extends "base.html" %}`)

It's up to you to decide what belongs there. But typically it will be the 'skeleton' of the page, the base.html you have posted in the question is a good example of a base template.

The `{% block ____ %}` tags define a place in the template where extending templates can substitute their own content. So, for example, where you have:

```
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
```

...the extending template can contain just:

```
{% block content %}
    some content here
{% endblock %}
```

and when rendered you get:

```
<div id="content">
    some content here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

These are Django template tags. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/).